# reactjs child element not re-render while parent does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I got the following code in my reactjs project.

The idea behind this is to click the button, then the `editTodoStatus` function will change the complete state of the `lists` object.

```
  import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";
  class List extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        lists:TodoStore.getTodos()
      };
    }
    editTodoStatus(event){
       const id = event.target.parentNode.dataset.id;
       TodoActions.editTodoStatus(id);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      TodoStore.on("create", this.getStoreData.bind(this));
      TodoStore.on("edit", this.getStoreData.bind(this));
    }

    getStoreData(){
      this.setState({
        lists: TodoStore.getTodos()
      });
    }

    return(
     <div>    
     { 
        this.state.lists.map(
           function(todo){
              if (todo.complete){
                complete = <Button color="info"><i className="fa fa-check" /></Button>;
              }else{
                complete = <Button color="danger" onClick = {this.editTodoStatus.bind(this)} ><i className="fa fa-times" /></Button>;
              }
              return (
                  <li key = {todo.id} >
                    {complete}
                  </li>
              );
           }.bind(this)
        );
     }
     </div>
   );
}
export default List;
```

However, the app will re-render only the Button element and ignores the `<i>` element within it, which means that the `<i>` stays the same.

But if I remove the `<Button>` element, `<i>` will be re-rendered as expected.

I am not sure about the reason behind this and the solution to the issue.

Here's the link of my project. https://johnhckuo.github.io/Todo-List/

If you press the red button to make this todo item 'complete', you will see the problem(the color of the button changed, but not the icon in it)

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You're not returning anything in your mapping function

Comment: with you current code nothing should render, where you are using `complete` ?

Comment: @MayankShukla  
Sorry, I've simplified my code and forgot to add the return part :p
Edited!

Comment: @Axnyff Sorry, I forgot to add the return part ><  Post edited!

Comment: you are using any lib for `button` or you have defined that component?

Comment: @MayankShukla Button is imported from reactstrap. I've added more details to the example code

Comment: You should use filter instead of map , since you're applying a condition into your map loop

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif What? Each item in a list is being mapped to a component, that's why `map()` is used. `filter()` does something completely different.

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the correct this? In your function, this is this.state.lists, not your react component. You should use an arrow function in your map or bind the method in your constructor

Comment: @Axnyff Ah yes, I did bind `this` in my original project. I've edited my post and I also append the link of my project so you can see the problem. Thanks for the patience ><

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that no properties of Button are being changed and therefore React sees no reason to update child. Try using more straightforward syntax, while explicitly changing the properties for Button:

```
renderItem = (id, complete) => {
  return <li key={id}>
    <Button onClick={complete && this.editTodoStatus} color={`${complete ? 'info' : 'danger' }`}>
      <i className={`fa ${complete ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'}`}
    </Button>
  </li>;
};

render() {
  const { lists } = this.state;

  return ( 
    <div>
     { lists.map(todo => this.renderItem(todo.id, todo.complete)) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another useful tip is using React Fragment instead of an useless div parent:

```
 import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

 //...
 render() {
   return (
     <Fragment>
        //...same code as before, without useless div
     </Fragment>
   );

 }
```

Debug the editTodoStatus method to see if this is effectively triggering change.
Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the suggestions! :)
But the button is actually able to re-render, except for its child element `<i>`

Comment: I've tried your ways of explicitly changing the properties for Button. But the result is still the same.
However, if I replace the `<i>` tag with some plain text, the result just works fine!